# "BufferedReader.ready" vs. "while(BufferedReader.readLine()!=null)"

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am a novice when it comes to java. I wanted to read the stdout from a process started in java. I got the following code upon a google search:

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec(args);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    while(br.ready()){
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
    }
```

However, this code does not print the output that the process (say, ls) is supposed to produce (btw, I am on Linux, openJDK 1.6)

But if I change the while loop to:

```
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(line);
    }
```

it works as expected.

What is the problem with the previous code? According to what the java api doc said, I thought they were similar.

Comment: Edited the first code block, to reflect the actually intended code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the previous loop, you're simply looping on the ready state, not reading any bytes from the stream.

Comment: Does it mean that the first loop is infinite because br.ready() returns always true? In the first fragment of code, if I declare String line = null and the loop while (line == br.ready()){System.out.println(line); if(line==null) break; } is right?

Comment: There is a high likelihood of the loop entering infinite state. However, if the first call to `br.ready()` returns with a `false`, the loop will be exited. I believe that is the case here. Also, you can't equate a `String` to a boolean as you've shown. Remember that `ready()` returns a `boolean`.

Comment: it's not even clear where `line` comes from in the first loop

Comment: @adarshr, AlbertS, Kublai Khan: Sorry, now I have edited the code. Actually, I pasted the working code and then modified it, and forgot to change the line variable

Comment: @Santanu: I don't think it is entering inside that loop. Put another S.O.P statement and check.

Comment: @adarshr: Yes, you are correct. Why could that be? I thought br.ready() should return true, but it is not!

Comment: @Santanu: It will return true but after a small delay. But the first call would return false and your loop would've exited, giving no chance to enter it. Try putting `Thread.sleep(2000)` before the while loop and you'll see that it enters into an infinite loop.

Comment: @adarshr: Thanks. This is about blocking vs. non-blocking call, right? The br.ready() is probably a non-blocking call, and hence the Thread.sleep(2000) is needed, isn't it?

Comment: @adarshr Understood. Thanks, I wrote an error about equating a string to a boolean :)

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the `ready()` test, the command hasn't produced any output yet and it returns `false`, immediately ending the loop.

Your second code works because the `readLine()` call blocks until it reads an entire line. Without further control, the output of such a code is unpredictable since it depends on the amount of output produced by the command and the time it takes to complete.

This is a very simple scenario so it works most of the times but it is not a solution than can generally be applied.